# What's the difference between ethernet and serial cable?

Tags: cables, router

I am confused about the difference between ethernet and serial cable? Do they do different things or not? If so, what's the difference? Also, I would like to know the cable that is suitable for long-range connections between routers. (let's say 2 km) Thanks

Comment: So what serial cable you mean? What ports you are going to use at the routers, Ethernet?

Comment: Sorry if I get it wrong. I mean cable that is connected to the serial port. I have not decided on the port that I'm going to use yet though. Just wanna know what cable is more suitable. (I'm thinking about fiber optic or serial). NB: I don't really understand what a serial cable do

Comment: Are you asking about differences in the physical wires themselves or about the communication techniques in general? What is your maximum data rate?

Comment: Hi @ElliotAlderson, I'm asking about the communication techniques in general. And I am not actually implementing it in real scenario so there is no maximum data rate. I just wanna know which cable is more suitable for long-range transmission between routers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am confused about the difference between Ethernet [capital 'E'] and serial cable? Do they do different things or not?

They communicate between electronic devices but with different voltage levels, speeds, connectors, protocols, error-checking, etc.

> If so, what's the difference?

Too much to discuss here. You will find plenty of tutorials on the web.

> Also, I would like to know the cable that is suitable for long-range connections between routers. (Let's say 2 km).

Ethernet CAT5 connections are limited to about 100 m. For 2 km you probably need to consider fibre.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Appreciate it

Comment: There are commercial products that convert from and to fiber. For both serial and Ethernet.

Comment: RS232 is good for about 100m same as ethernet, RS422 and RS485 can go kilometers.